# sparklyr livy connection with Kerberos

Tags: r, kerberos, sparklyr, livy

I'm able to connect to non-Kerberized spark cluster through Livy service without problems from a *remote* Rstudio desktop (windows).

However, if the Kerberos security is enabled, the connection fails:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect("http://host:8998", method = "livy")
```

returning

```
Error in livy_validate_http_response("Failed to create livy session",  : 
Livy operation is unauthorized. Try spark_connect with config = livy_config()
```

using `sparklyr_0.5.6-9002` and MIT Kerberos for Windows for the authentication.

On the other hand, from *within* the cluster (i.e. through `curl`) the connection is successful.

What am I doing wrong? What additional settings are required for such connection?

The `livy_config(..., username, password)` config seems to be forming only a `Authorization: Basic ...` header, though here I'd suspect a `Negotiate` or `Kerberos`(?) should be required instead.

Are there any other possible configurations I'm missing?

NB: same error is returned from RStudio Server (web) after `kinit`'ing from the shell with authorized user.

Comment: livy server should be configured for the launch, auth like the below one.

Comment: In the livy.conf file, you should put `livy.server.launch.kerberos.principal = XXX`, `livy.server.launch.kerberos.keytab = XXX`, `livy.server.auth.kerberos.principal = 'XXX', `livy.server.auth.kerberos.keytab = spnego keytab`. Please refer to http://henning.kropponline.de/2016/11/06/connecting-livy-to-a-secured-kerberized-hdp-cluster/

Comment: @KangrokLee Thanks for your reply! The livy is properly configured (I probably forgot to mention that in the post, will edit), your suggested settings are set and the livy is working fine from within the cluster (i.e. from RStudio Server or curl). The problem described arises when trying to connect from remote Rstudio desktop on Windows.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @ansek No, not directly through Kerberos. However, a workaround was to connect through [Knox Gateway](https://knox.apache.org/) with [Livy added as a service](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/70499/adding-livy-server-as-service-to-apache-knox.html). This way the Kerberos is handled by Knox within the cluster, while from remote Rstudio desktop client only the ``Basic`` authentication is required (which is through SSL, so doesn't seem too bad). Note that in my case it also required some minor tweaking  of ``sparklyr``'s source code, but not sure whether it is fixed with latest updates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming late to the party, but I had the same problem and was finally able to solve it. This could be useful to others.

Of course this may depend a lot on your cluster configuration. I'm using `sparklyr` 1.5.0, and MIT Kerberos for Windows, with direct connection to Livy (no Knox proxy) running in a Cloudera HDP cluster (Spark 2.3.0). In my case an extra HTTP header was required, see below.

If your cluster doesn't allow outgoing internet connections, you should also first save the SparklyR server-side jar on HDFS (by default it is automatically downloaded from GitHub).

```
library(sparklyr)
SPARK_VERSION = "2.3.0"

lcfg = livy_config(
  negotiate = TRUE, 
  custom_headers = list("X-Requested-By"="<user_name>"))
lcfg$sparklyr.livy.jar = "hdfs:///path/to/sparklyr-2.3-2.11.jar"

sc = spark_connect(
  master = "http://livyserver:8999", method = "livy", 
  version = SPARK_VERSION,
  config = lcfg)
```

For debugging, a first step might be to test your Livy setup outside of the cluster but without R: see https://livy.apache.org/examples/

Comment: Looks promising, will try it out as soon as I'll get the chance! As a side note, do you have a direct access to the Kerberos server? I've later noticed that many issues came from using Kerberos through an ssh tunnel (with proper fqdn in hosts file) which sometimes resulted in problems with GSS Negotiate.

Comment: I'm on a VPN, no SSH tunnel, so can't tell anything about that problem